# SQL: need to query over 5900 tables for a specific value, but encountering memory allocation error

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

In Microsoft SQL Server 2008, I'm trying to return a list of Table Names that contain a specific value within a specific field.  Due to the amount of tables it's querying, I get a memory allocation error and it crashes.
I want to be able to return the tablename for ONLY those tables where the value exists and hopefully avoid the memory allocation issue, as well as avoid having to read through 5900 rows in the log, looking for results...

I'll walk through an example of my code below, searching for a field called PAINTCOLOUR that contains "BLUE".

```
SET NOCOUNT ON
go

DECLARE @tablename nvarchar(256)
DECLARE @sqlStatement nvarchar(300)
```

Get all tables from DB where there exists a field called "PAINTCOLOUR"

```
DECLARE tnames_cursor CURSOR FOR SELECT A.name
FROM [dbName.dbo.sysobjects] A
    WHERE A.name in (SELECT B.RECNAME FROM TBLRECFIELD B WHERE B.FIELDNAME     = 'PAINTCOLOUR' AND B.RECNAME = A.name) 
    ORDER BY A.name
```

Loop through tnames_cursor, feeding each table name into Select statement below

```
OPEN tnames_cursor

FETCH NEXT FROM tnames_cursor INTO @tablename

WHILE (@@fetch_status <> -1)
BEGIN
    IF (@@fetch_status <> -2)
```

Select against the passed-in @tablename to see if the value of "BLUE" exists in the PAINTCOLOUR field, and if so, how many times.
MY ISSUE IS HERE:  Can I somehow write this query better to avoid the memory allocation issue and avoid having to see all the rows in the log where no results were found on a given table?

```
SET @sqlStatement = 'select '''+@tablename+''' AS ''RECORD NAME'', COUNT(*) AS ''COUNT OF RECORDS'' from '+@tablename+' where PAINTCOLOUR = ''BLUE'' HAVING COUNT (*) > 0 '


EXEC (@sqlStatement)

    FETCH NEXT FROM tnames_cursor INTO @tablename
END
go
DEALLOCATE tnames_cursor
go
```

Comment: What is that exact error you are receiving? How many tables of the 5900 end up having that column name?

Comment: You do know you can get table data for `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` right? You can use this data to narrow down the tables under consideration.

Comment: Thanks to you both for your questions.  I found a way to get around my issue by dumping my results into a temp table and querying it later.  Mike: only 35 of the over 5900 tables actually had a result.  Johan, I'm working in a Peoplesoft environment, so querying against PSRECFIELD works just fine to grab all the tables that have the specific field I need to query.  I didn't know about INFORMATION_SCHEMA though, so thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: I've got the answer written out for my example, but I can't post it for another 7 hours...  ;)

Comment: Do you really need the row count, or are you just interested in the table names?

Answer (score 1):

So I see that you already figured it out, but I was intrigued. Here is my answer, that avoids using counts, so I think it will be a lot faster. It uses INFORMATION_SCHEMA to limit the number of tables based on column names and an EXISTS query rather than a GROUP BY to look for the values. If you are really interested in the count of records with BLUE, then this won't work.

```
SET NOCOUNT ON

DECLARE @tableschema nvarchar(256);
DECLARE @tablename nvarchar(256);
DECLARE @sqlStatement nvarchar(300);

DECLARE @tblOutput TABLE (TableName nvarchar(256));

Declare tnames_cursor Cursor FOR
    Select t.table_schema, t.table_name
        from information_schema.tables t
            Inner Join information_schema.columns c
            on t.table_schema = c.table_schema and t.table_name=c.table_name
    Where c.column_name='PAINTCOLOUR' and Table_type='BASE TABLE'

OPEN tnames_cursor
FETCH NEXT FROM tnames_cursor INTO @tableschema, @tablename
WHILE @@fetch_status = 0
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @rows int;
        Set @sqlStatement = 'Select @rows=1 Where Exists (select 1 from ' 
            + @tableschema + '.' + @tablename 
            + ' where PAINTCOLOUR = ''BLUE'')'

        exec sp_executesql @sqlStatement, @params=N'@rows INT OUTPUT', @rows=@rows OUTPUT

        If @rows > 0 
            INSERT INTO @tblOutput Values (@tablename)

        FETCH NEXT FROM tnames_cursor INTO @tableschema, @tablename
    END

CLOSE tnames_cursor
DEALLOCATE tnames_cursor

SET NOCOUNT OFF

Select * from @tblOutput
```

Comment: Thanks Bill.   The row count isn't an absolute necessity.  I think we could live without it and query the specific record if we wanted to see it.  I'm curious to see how much faster it is if I write it your way, though it takes only 1 minute, roughly, to execute right now.

Comment: I was able to run the query, but it didn't return the results I was looking for (returned over 9000 rows and when I queried one of the more suspicious looking tables, my "paint colour" didn't exist on that table at all).  Will have to look into it more closely later on to see how I need to tweak it, as at first glance, the SQL seems to be accurate.  For now though, what I'm running meets my purpose.  Thanks very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

My solution:  I created a temp table and wrote my results into it where the count was greater than 0.  Then I simply query the tmp table.  Note: I drop the tmp table and re-create it each time as we work in unstable environments that are refreshed often.

--Purpose of SQL is to return a list of Table Names where there is a value of "Blue" in the PAINTCOLOUR field.

```
SET NOCOUNT ON
go

DECLARE @tablename nvarchar(256)
DECLARE @sqlStatement nvarchar(300)
```

--First, get all tables from DB where there exists a field called "PAINTCOLOUR" and store in tnames_cursor

```
DECLARE tnames_cursor CURSOR FOR SELECT A.name
FROM [dbPath] A
    WHERE A.name in (SELECT B.RECNAME FROM TBLRECFIELD B WHERE  B.FIELDNAME  = 'PAINTCOLOUR' AND B.RECNAME = A.name) 
    ORDER BY A.name
```

-- NEW: If MY_TMP_TBL exists, drop it

```
IF object_id('dbo.MY_TMP_TBL') is not null
DROP TABLE dbo.MY_TMP_TBL
```

-- NEW: Create temporary table MY_TMP_TBL

```
CREATE TABLE MY_TMP_TBL
(
TABLENAME varchar(255),
COUNTOFRECORDS varchar(255)
)
```

--Loop through tnames_cursor, feeding each table name into Select statement below

```
OPEN tnames_cursor

FETCH NEXT FROM tnames_cursor INTO @tablename

WHILE (@@fetch_status <> -1)
BEGIN
    IF (@@fetch_status <> -2)
```

--UPDATED: Select against each @tablename to see if the value of "BLUE" exists in the PAINTCOLOUR field, and if so, how many times.  Write results to the temp table
--MY_TMP_TBL where the count is greater that 0.

```
SET @sqlStatement = 'INSERT INTO MY_TMP_TBL (TABLENAME, COUNTOFRECORDS)    SELECT '''+@tablename+''', COUNT(*) from PS_'+RTRIM(UPPER(@tablename))+' where PAINTCOLOUR = ''BLUE'' HAVING COUNT (*) > 0 '


EXEC (@sqlStatement)

    FETCH NEXT FROM tnames_cursor INTO @tablename
END
go
DEALLOCATE tnames_cursor
go
```

-- NEW:  Now you can query the MY_TMP_TBL for the results.

```
SELECT * FROM MY_TMP_TBL;
```